# Checking type of big integer values without sign

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
print isinstance(2147483647, int) # True - max signed 32-bit integer
print isinstance(4294967295, int) # False - max unsigned 32-bit integer
print isinstance(18446744073709551615, int) # False - max unsigned 64-bit integer
```

How to check if value is unsigned 32-bit integer and unsigned 64-bit integer?

Comment: Why do you care what type it is?

Comment: To check the type just use `type()`. What are you really asking here? Is it perhaps the underlying C type being used, or maybe whether a given integer will fit in a particular C type? The question is unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just intended to check whether  the number fits in a 32 bit integer or 64 bit integer, there is a method called `bit-length` which you can check and determine if the result is less than 32 or not.

For ex.

```
>>> def Is32or64(x):
    return 32 if x.bit_length() < 32 else 64

>>> Is32or64(2**30)
32
>>> Is32or64(2**40)
64
```

Comment: Doesn't work for numbers greater than 2**64, and it's not clear if you mean to say it would fit in a signed or an unsigned integer of that size.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths Probably you have missed the part where I have said `If you just intended to check whether the number fits in a 32 bit integer or 64 bit integer`. And OP is happy with the answer too :-)

Comment: So what if I want to check if 2**100 fits in a 32 or 64 bit integer? Or are you suggesting that it only works if you first check that `x` does fit in 64 bits? And some numbers that fit in an unsigned 32 bit int don't fit in a signed 32 bit int and it's not clear which you mean to test. The OP may be happy, but I think the OP is a bit confused.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths That was the reason of the initial caveat. I am not claiming this would work with integer's of higher bit length. Off course 2**100 would not fit in a 64-bit integer but that was not OP intended and not this answer is claiming to achieve. If you need something robust as such you have to do an elaborate check which I wanted to avoid for the sake of simplicity understanding, OP is not at all interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can not check for unsigned integer types because there are no unsigned integer types.

Python 2 has two types for integers: `int` (fixed range, platform dependent, 32-bit at least) and `long` (infinitely big integer). Both are signed.

In your example, the first value has type `int` and the other two are `long`. If you want to know if a value fits into range of 64-bit integer, do an ordinary comparison:

```
if (x >= 0) and (x < 2**64):
    pass
```

Starting with Python versions 2.7 and 3.1, there is `int.bit_length()` method which calculates how many bits a binary representation of the number has, ignoring the sign.

Comment: You can also write conveniently `if 0 <= x < 2**64`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `2**x`:

```
2147483647 == 2**32
18446744073709551615 == 2**64
```